# Unresolved reference: antlr

Tags: build.gradle, antlr, importerror

When I am importing antlr, as in below

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*
...
```

I get the error message saying `Unresolved reference: antlr`.

Not quite sure if you need this info, but my `build.gradle` is currently as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.2.1'
    id 'java'
}

group 'me.ylee'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.6.21"
    implementation "net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.11.0"
    // Dependency on local binaries
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

intellij {
    plugins = ['Kotlin', 'java']
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

How can I successfully import the antlr? Do I need to include antlr somewhere in the `build.gradle`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I realized I needed to add antlr-related dependencies as shown in the revised `build.gradle` as shown below:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.2.1'
    id 'java'
    id 'antlr'
}

group 'me.ylee'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.6.21'
    implementation "net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.11.0"
    antlr 'org.antlr:antlr4:4.10.1'
    implementation 'org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.10.1'
    // Dependency on local binaries
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

intellij {
    plugins = ['Kotlin', 'java']
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```